# Search for data from list and delete row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in Sheet1. I need to search in Sheet1 for terms in Sheet2-ColumnA.

The exclusion list in Sheet2-ColumnA does not match the cell contents in Sheet1, but is found within the cell contents (Ex: find "orange" in "yellow;orange" or "orange;yellow").

If that criteria is found, delete the row. If it doesn't find the criteria, continue on down the list until it reaches an empty cell.

I recorded one round of this, but I need to modify it to loop through the entire exclusion list until it reaches an empty cell in the exclusion list.

```
Sub ExclusionList()
'
' ExclusionList Macro
' Find terms from exclusion list and delete row
'
' Go to sheet2 and select first term in exclusion list
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select

' Copy cell contents and find in sheet 1
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="orange", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

' Delete row if found
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

In this example, "orange" is the criteria in Sheet2 A1. If it is possible to skip the copy/paste and refer directly to the exclusion list in the Cells.Find() function it seems like that would clean up the code and be more efficient overall.

Comment: You almost never need `.Select` in VBA, so you can change the first part of the code to `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Copy` I'm also not sure why you're copying though - is it to get the value of the cell, so you can search for that value in Sheet1?

Comment: You're right - the copying is to get the value of the cell so I can search for it in Sheet1. I haven't modified the code form the macro recorder beyond adding comments so I know what is happening where in the code. Thanks for the tip on .Select!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Here is a useful resource on [avoiding Select/Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). This shortens code considerably and makes it more effective.

```
Sub ExclusionList()

Dim r As Range, rFind As Range

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Each r In .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'loop through every cell in sheet2 column A
        Set rFind = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:=r.Value, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then 'check that value is found to avoid error on next line
            rFind.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank you for the code and thank you for the resources!